# New SuSE install intermittently freezes

Tags: system-installation, video, freeze, suse

I've just installed the latest Gnome SuSE from their website (downloaded from their site yesterday). I grabbed the LiveCD, put it on a USB stick, booted from it, and used the included installer to install onto a freshly wiped drive.

The installation went smoothly. No errors, package updates all worked, ran Yast to configure the wired network connection and everything was off and running. The only additional change I've made was to go into the display settings and turn off mirroring for my second monitor.

Now, the machine intermittently freezes a minute or so after boot. 
The mouse sort of works – if I move it, it'll respond 10-30 seconds later. 
I can initially hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console, but that also freezes after a few seconds. 
I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to Gnome, but then even the intermittent mouse will not respond. The only option at that point is a hard reboot via the reset button on the case.

This is a custom machine with a P51 motherboard, i7 quad core, 16 GB of RAM, 2x GTX580s (I haven't changed the video driver from what the installer auto-configured), and a 1 TB drive with no other operating systems.

I previously had Windows 7 Ultimate x64 running for over a year with no difficulties, which leads me to believe that this is not a hardware problem.

Any suggestions on where to start looking? I'm comfortable with the shell and normal app installation, etc., but am not really a Linux expert.

**Update**

After leaving it frozen for a few minutes, I saw this:

[image: photograph of screen, showing what looks like video memory corruption]

And later, the messages:

```
[  OK  ] Started LSB: VMware Tools Daemon
[  OK  ] Started LSB: X Display Manager
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Latest being the latest stable (12.3) or the latest development build?

Comment: @schaiba stable.

Comment: Try booting into non GUI target - add `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` (or any other - see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#Boot_Kernel_Command_Line) - and see whether it still freezes.

Comment: @peterph I'm having trouble figuring out where that should be applied. Hitting 'E' in GRUB and editing that file, adding systemd.unit=... appears to do nothing at all.

Comment: `systemd.unit=multi-...` should be appended to the kernel command line. I'm not familiar with GRUB, but editing it with 'e' sounds reasonable. What exactly do you mean by: *"appears to do nothing at all"*?

Comment: @peterph even entering random asdghffd text into the startup config (editing pre-boot in grub) doesnt generate an error, which I tried because the systemd.init setting also did nothing. In the mean time, I've played with removing nouveau with zypper in the shell, and the system appears stable. Now I have to figure out how to install the Nvidia drivers. :/

Comment: @peterph (I'm guessing the options I  editing in grub simply aren't being read. Looking for more information on editing kernel boot parameters in SuSE. This was easy in Ubuntu.

Comment: Unrecognised command line options are silently ignored, I believe.